# html scale div for html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, jspdf, html2canvas

Context: Vue app to fill Forms and then plug the values into a template.
This preview should be exported using html2canvas + jsPDF.

Problem: on mobile devices the unresponsive template adjusts to viewport, i. e. things just overlap and this broken view then gets exported by html2canvas.

Question: How to make a div always appear the same on mobile and desktop, even if it is larger that parent divs and the viewport?
I. e. how to scale a div
OR
free it from all inherited box styles and add make overlay visible?
Please let me know if you spot a better solution.

Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Did you set the `viewport` meta tag?

Comment: @JavaScript Yes, like so: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />. How would I need to manipulate that? Remember, the rest of the app is responsive, it is just this template. (is an iframe a solution?)